# How does Implicit wait work in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In implicit wait if we specify the wait time as 30s and if the element becomes available at 5s then will it wait for the entire duration of 30s or it'll continue the execution after 5 sec ??

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit wait:** It will wait until enite duration before it throws No Such Element Exception. The default setting is 0. When you set the time, web driver will wait for 30s time and web driver keep polling to DOM after every 500 miliseconds until it finds your specified element before it throws Exception.

Yes it will continue with executing immediately once it find/finds the element/elements.

You may also understand that to be the case from a simple example below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(50)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='NKcBbd']")
```